# Python list IndexError with transfering lists to objects

Tags: python, list

So I'm working on an assignment, and I've come to a obstacle I can't seem to overcome. I'm essentially designing a rudimentary Library System. I have to read in from a file the books, librarians, and patrons and parse them in to lists then to objects. I've gotten the parsing to lists part down and have them ready to be used to create objects. Here's where I have the issue when I try to read from the lists I get and **IndexError**, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

My list where the first item is the **ISBN**, then the **Title**, then **Author**, then it repeats, i.e. *['123','The Scarlet Letter', 'Nathaniel Hawthorne']*

```
self._bookList = ['123', 'The Scarlet Letter', 'Nathaniel Hawthorne', '456', 'Lord of the Rings', 'JRR Tolkien', '789', 'A Tale of Two Cities', 'Charles Dickens', '10112', 'Wuthering Heghts', 'Emily Bronte', '131415', 'Jane Eyre', 'Charlotte Bronte', '161718', 'Pride and Predudice', 'Jane Austin']
```

Snippet where I have the problem. I've tried using len(self._bookList)-1, +1, +2, +3. Nothing seems to work.

```
def _addToCollection(self):
    i = 0
    while i < len(self._bookList):
        ISBN = []
        ISBN.append(self._bookList[i])
        title = []
        title.append(self._bookList[i+1])
        author = []
        author.append(self._bookList[i+2])      
        #print(self._bookList[i],self._bookList[i+1],self._bookList[i+2])
        BookCollection.addBook(self,str(ISBN[i]),str(title[i]),str(author[i]))
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are assigning empty lists during every iteration. When you call `ISBN[i]` the list always has only one element. Therefore it fails as soon as `i` becomes larger than zero.

One way to fix it is to notice that you don't need the lists at all:

```
def _addToCollection(self):
    i = 0
    while i < len(self._bookList):
        ISBN = self._bookList[i]
        title = self._bookList[i+1]
        author = self._bookList[i+2]
        BookCollection.addBook(self,str(ISBN),str(title),str(author))
        i += 3
```

I'd suggest instead that you take a look at the grouper [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) as this seems to do exactly what you need:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

You can use it like this:

```
for ISBN, title, author in grouper(3, self._bookList):
    BookCollection.addBook(self, str(ISBN), str(title), str(author))
```

Comment: When I add the three holding lists to the beginning like so. It goes into an infinite loop 
`def _addToCollection(self):
        i = 0
        ISBN = []
        title = []
        author = []
        while i < len(self._bookList):
            ISBN.append(self._bookList[i])
            title.append(self._bookList[i+1])
            author.append(self._bookList[i+2])              BookCollection.addBook(self,str(ISBN[i]),str(title[i]),str(author[i]))
            i += 1`

Comment: You don't need to use lists at all.

Comment: I see how it works, but now I'm getting an NameError.

`def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


    def _addToCollection(self):
        for ISBN, title, author in grouper(3, self._bookList):
            BookCollection.addBook(self, str(ISBN), str(title), str(author))`

Comment: @Mark Byers: So I need to essentially dissect whats functions are used from grouper according to the documentation and also implement those?

Comment: @Mark Byers: I used `from itertools import *` and I'm still getting a NameError. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: @Kemiv: `grouper` is not a function in itertools (dont ask why) it's just mentioned in the receipes. Paste it into your code.

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: I currently do have it pasted in my code exactly how its formatted above in Mark's answer.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I appreciate the tip about the grouper function and recipes, which I didn't even know existed. But I think its more complicated than this assignment demands. So I tried to implement your initial suggestion, but still received an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **init** method and just do this

```
a = BookCollection.addBook(*self._bookList)
```

Comment: How would that help? I'm confused by your response

Comment: Rather than do a complicated construction method just unpack the contents of the list straight into addBook